# Use consistent lecture notes equation numbers in slides

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a set of lecture notes with accompanying slides. As the slides only focus on the more important formulas the lecture notes contain more equations than the slides. However, I would like to use the same equation numbers in the slides as are used in the lecture notes.

I could probably do this manually, but is there a way to do this in an 'automated fashion' meaning that when I change the formula in the lecture notes a recompilation of the slides will adjust the formula (and possibly the equation number)?

I guess this has several subquestions:

- How do I reference equations from a different document?
- How do I repeat the content of an equation based on the label?

Comment: The simplest way is write them manually by using `\tag`. Like `\begin{equation}\tag{3}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}`. For cross referencing between document serves `xr` package. See https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf

Comment: thanks for the xr suggestion. I am wondering whether there exists a solution where I do not need to retype the equations or copy/paste them. As I would then need to correct them in 2 places if I make an error.

Comment: If using beamer have a look at article mode.

Comment: To avoid having to retype (or copy and paste) lengthy equations, you may consider creating macros for them and storing the macros in an external file that's loaded by both the lecture notes file and the beamer slides file. That, and use the facilities of the `xr` package to get the cross-references going across documents.